# Can a CFM56-3C engine be converted into a CFM56-3B1?

Tags: jet-engine

Is it possible to take a CFM56-3C engine and modify it to a CFM56-3B1 engine? I own a CFM56-3C engine but my customer would like to install a CFM56-3B1 engine on his plane. Can this be done?

Comment: A good subquestion would be : how common are those engines? If there are too many parts that differ, it may be hard (technically and legally) to convert one into the other.

Comment: This question raises _so_ many other questions...

Answer (score 2):

In theory, I think that should be possible, as the -3B is a lower thrust rating than the -3C (going to higher thrust rating would be harder).  However, you would have to ask CFM.  I think they are the only ones that could answer.